# Accessing S3 buckets with same access policy from EC2 instance with different results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have two different buckets in the same account and they both have identical access policies

First bucket policy is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy0",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/MyEC2Role0",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/MyEC2Role1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-uploads",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-uploads/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Second bucket policy is just the same but changing the bucket name

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/MyEC2Role0",
                    "arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/MyEC2Role1"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-exchange",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-exchange/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I access both buckets from an EC2 instance running Win16 Server. The instance role is `MyEC2Role1` and it has assigned the policy `AmazonS3FullAccess` and it belongs to same account as well.

When I run the AWS CLI command `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-uploads/`, it's successful and lists the bucket's contents. However when I run `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-exchange/`, it raises following error

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

I've compared buckets properties and policies once and again and I haven't found any difference, I've searched at AWS Documentation for troubleshot for that error, I've also googled for a long, I've recreated the bucket and anything worked.

Has anyone had the same problem? Any idea about a solution or anythin to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything looks okay. By the way, either of your techniques would be sufficient to grant access. That is, the IAM Role assigned to the instance with `AmazonS3FullAccess` would be sufficient (if not overly-generous) to grant it access to your S3 buckets. Alternatively, the Bucket Policy would be sufficient. Using the IAM Policy is more 'elegant' because it does not require changes to every bucket desired. My guess is that either the buckets are in different AWS Accounts (can you view them both on the same screen in the S3 management console?) or you aren't using the expected credentials.

Comment: I've checked that both buckets are in the same region. Regarding credentials, commands are run one immediately after other so I can't think how different credentials could be used.
I'll try your suggestion about using just IAM policies to grant access in order to put away as many potential misconfiguration as possible

Comment: Both buckets are in the same AWS Account? That is, if you access the S3 management console, are both displayed on the same screen?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same account (I actually have just one), and same value is shown in column 'AWS Region' so region match as well.
I've changed permissions in the way you suggested, and now access is granted via own policy and restricted to required buckets only, no more full access with `AmazonS3FullAccess` policy. And still I can list contents in 'bucket-uploads` but get an error if I query `bucket-exchange`.
By the way, I've realized that I can't access any bucket created in the last 3 days (`bucket-uploads`exists 10 days ago). I'm atonished!

Comment: Just for clarifying, own policy is attached to EC2 instance role and buckets' policies have been deleted

Comment: It's starting to sound like an AWS issue. If you have AWS Support, I'd recommend giving them a call.

Comment: Just an idea... Try specifying a specific region when making the call, eg `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname --region us-west-2`. Try a few different regions (even ones where the buckets are _not_ located). Probably won't help since both buckets are in the same region, but maybe!

Comment: I've tried and no success. Thanks anyway for your suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my error so the solution to my problem.

My EC2 instance belongs to a VPC which defines an endpoint with an attached policy that controls access to S3 buckets. It's my fault to not realize that and not mention it in my original question.

I've modified the endpoint's policy to include the bucket that I want to access to from my EC2 instance, and that allows desired operations and puts error away.

In conclusion, if you can't access to a bucket from an EC2 instance and its policy (or S3 bucket policy) is correct, check your VPC, its endpoints and their policies